# Opacity on two divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have two div's which looks like this

```
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner>
   </div>
</div>

#outer {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
 opacity:0.50;
}
```

The problem is that I get opacity and in the inner div. I know that I can put inner div outside the outer div, but this is not solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that's because you are fading `#outer` and everything **inside** it.

If you are only trying to fade the background colour you have two options:

1. Use a transparent .gif as a background image.
2. use rgba. Rg. `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)` is equals to Black with 60% opacity.

****EDIT****

Just realised it's for Internet Explorer 6, please be more clear next time.
In this case, *rgba* will not work, so give up on that.
You can still do so with transparent background image, but you'd need a jQuery plugin to make IE6 support .png images. Here's one http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

Comment: refhat added IE  tag. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba background colour to set opacity instead - your problem is just a standard css problem.